# An error when sending PATCH with Postman to Asp.net Core webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I have a model,

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ItemIds { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

and a repository,

```
public interface IOrderRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Order> Get();
    Order Get(Guid id);
    void Add(Order order);
    void Update(Guid id, Order order);
    // other irrelevant code has been deleted for simplicity
}

public class MemoryOrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    private readonly IList<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();
    public IEnumerable<Order> Get() => _orders;

    public Order Get(Guid id) => _orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
    public void Add(Order order) => _orders.Add(order);

    public void Update(Guid id, Order order)
    {
        var target = _orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
        if (target != null) target.ItemIds = order.ItemIds;
    }
    // other irrelevant code has been deleted for simplicity
}
```

that have been registered in `Startup.cs` as follows.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) =>
        services.AddSingleton<IOrderRepository, MemoryOrderRepository>()
                .AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Additional relevant nuget packages are already installed as follows.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.1" />
```

A testing controller is given as follows.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class OrderController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IOrderRepository repo;

    public OrderController(IOrderRepository repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() => Ok(repo.Get());

    [HttpGet("{id:guid}")]
    public IActionResult Get(Guid id) => Ok(repo.Get(id));

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(Order order)
    {
        Order target = new Order()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            ItemIds = order.ItemIds
        };

        repo.Add(target);

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = target.Id }, null);
    }

    [HttpPatch("{id:guid}")]
    public IActionResult Patch(Guid id, JsonPatchDocument<Order> order)
    {
        Order target = repo.Get(id);
        if (target == null)
            return NotFound(new { Message = $"Item with id {id} does not exist." });


        order.ApplyTo(target);
        repo.Update(id, target);
        return Ok();
    }

    // other irrelevant code is deleted for simplicity
}
```

Using Postman, I successfully created a new order by sending POST verb to the server first and then confirming the result by sending GET verb as follows.

[image]

[image]

## Question

I attempted to partially update the order with the following but failed.

[image]

The error message is

> The JSON patch document was malformed and could not be parsed.

What is wrong and how to fix it?

Instead of

```
{
    "ItemIds": ["xyz","123"]
}
```

I also tried

```
{
    "op":"replace",
    "path":"/ItemIds",
    "value": ["xyz","123"]
}
```

Both do not help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: your examples don't seem to be in an array?   [ { ... } ]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-2.2#json-patch-example-1) for json patch you need to pass an array of operations instead of single object, like so

```
[
  {
    "op":"replace",
    "path":"/ItemIds",
    "value": ["xyz","123"]
  }
]
```